# How to change a css class from a ng-include to a view (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-view

I'm looking to change my background-image on buttons click.

I tried to use on my div:  `ng-init="select=1" ng-class="{'first-part': select == 1}" ng-class="{'sec-part': select == 2}"`

and to check the varable to change the class but I can't using this variable out of the view.

My index code is like this :

```
 <body ng-app="myApp">

    <div ng-include="'views/header.html'"></div>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <div ng-include="'views/footer.html'"></div>

</body>
```

So my buttons are on the view and the css class to change on header.html.

Thanks guys for your help.

Nam's

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the documentation (and examples) of [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). You'll see:

```
<p ng-class="{strike: deleted, bold: important, 'has-error': error}">Map Syntax Example</p>
```

That means for you, you should try:

```
ng-class="{'first-part': select == 1, 'sec-part': select == 2}"
```

Comment: Thanks iWork for your answer, I've already tried to use ng-class exactly as you show me but on header.html file the select value never change. Maybe because ng-click are in the view and the class to change in another file ?